# .NET Dynamic method. Best performance

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, dynamic, .net-4.0

What is the best way to create dynamic method on a fly but have it same efficient if it was compiled in VS?

Say I want create a calculator. User inputs formula say A + B / C * 0.5;

What I want is to be able to create something like Func which will accept A,B,C as double parameters and return double.

The parameters type and the return type are always double. Number of parameters are variable but at least one.

These formulas can be changed / added often. Once a formula 'compiled' it will be part of low latency code which can be called 1000 times / sec.

I need to find simple and reliable way to build it but it **must have exact performance qualities of statically built and optimised method**.

Comment: Do you already have a mechanism to get the operators?

Comment: no. i am just planning out...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found Microsoft blog on this ([Generating Dynamic Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) ) and compared performance between static method, compiled expression tree and IL injection.

Here is the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double acc = 0;

        var il = ILFact();
        il.Invoke(1);

        var et = ETFact();
        et(1);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            long time1, time2;

            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
            {
                var result = CSharpFact(i);
                acc += result;
            }

            sw.Stop();

            time1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
            {
                double result = il.Invoke(i);
                acc += result;
            }

            sw.Stop();

            time2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
            {
                var result = et(i);
                acc += result;
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,6} {2,6}", time1, time2, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}...\n", acc);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Func<int, int> ILFact()
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod(
        "factorial", typeof(int),
        new[] { typeof(int) }
        );

        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        var result = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
        var startWhile = il.DefineLabel();
        var returnResult = il.DefineLabel();

        // result = 1

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, result);

        // if (value <= 1) branch end

        il.MarkLabel(startWhile);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ble_S, returnResult);

        // result *= (value--)

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Sub);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Starg_S, 0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, result);

        // end while

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, startWhile);

        // return result

        il.MarkLabel(returnResult);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<int, int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int>));
    }

    static Func<int, int> ETFact()
    {
        // Creating a parameter expression.
        ParameterExpression value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "value");

        // Creating an expression to hold a local variable. 
        ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "result");

        // Creating a label to jump to from a loop.
        LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(int));

        // Creating a method body.
        BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(

        // Adding a local variable.
        new[] { result },

        // Assigning a constant to a local variable: result = 1
        Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Constant(1)),

        // Adding a loop.
        Expression.Loop(

        // Adding a conditional block into the loop.
        Expression.IfThenElse(

        // Condition: value > 1
        Expression.GreaterThan(value, Expression.Constant(1)),

        // If true: result *= value --
        Expression.MultiplyAssign(result,
        Expression.PostDecrementAssign(value)),

        // If false, exit from loop and go to a label.
        Expression.Break(label, result)
        ),

        // Label to jump to.
        label
        )
        );

        // Compile an expression tree and return a delegate.
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(block, value).Compile();
    }

    static int CSharpFact(int value)
    {
        int result = 1;
        while (value > 1)
        {
            result *= value--;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Here are 3 runs made on i7-920. Build - Release x64

```
583    542    660
577    578    666
550    558    652
576    575    648
570    574    641
560    554    640
558    551    650
561    551    666
624    638    683
564    581    647

-3778851060...

482    482    557
489    490    580
514    517    606
541    537    626
551    524    641
563    555    631
552    558    644
572    541    652
591    549    652
562    552    639

-3778851060...

482    482    560
507    503    591
525    543    596
555    531    609
553    556    634
540    552    640
579    598    635
607    554    639
588    585    679
547    560    643

-3778851060...
```

Averages: 554 549 634

Static vs IL - **IL 1% faster** (!) no idea why though

Static vs ET - **static 14% faster than expression tree**

---

**EDIT (Feb 2014)** : I just ran the code above (with very slight modifications) on .NET 4.5 and faster CPU and got the new sets of results: **Method / ET - 9%, Method / IL - 4%**

Hence the previous results are not valid any more - **the static method call is always faster**..

*Not sure whether it is new hardware (*i7-3820*) or new .NET or perhaps I did something wrong in the old test.*

*Another interesting result is that in **32-bit** the very same code shows **absolutely NO difference** between the 3.*

```
Method IL     ET    
--------------------
368    382    399
367    382    399
367    382    399
367    382    400
367    383    400
367    382    399
367    383    399
367    382    399
367    382    399
367    383    400
367    382    399
367    382    399
367    382    399
367    382    399
367    383    400
367    382    400
367    383    399
367    383    400
367    382    399
367    382    400

-7557702120...

--------------------
367.05 382.30 399.35
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create and `Compile()` an expression tree.

Comment: could you give me a rough idea how to do this please?

Comment: @Bobb: After you parse your string, build an expression tree using the `Expression.*` methods.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: As long as I understood it expression need to be declared first. ie `              ExpressionTreeBuilder b = new ExpressionTreeBuilder();
            Expression<Func<double, double, double, double>> e = b.GetExpressionTreeFromString("a + b - c");
            var d = e.Compile();
            var result = d(1, 2, 3);` 
@@@ question - how do you go about variable number of parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an dynamic calculator that uses compiled code.  The source is available.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx

Comment: Chris using CSharpCodeProvider you will end with hundreds of dlls hunging about in few days... as long as I understand this it compiles a new dll on every call. is that right?

Comment: @Bobb - I haven't fully tested it, sorry.  Just throwing it out there as a resource.

Comment: no thats fine. I know about CSharpCodeProvider and if I wont find another way I'd try your code. It just I wanted to find something more manageable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depend on usage and optimization.
Benchmark can lie if your tests are not perfect.
You have to know the rules to make it right.

The first rules

- static method can be optimized at compile time and can be inlined.
- IL emitted method (DynamicMethod) can be faster in term of pure IL because you can optimized like you want (if you are able to do it better than standard optimizer)
- Expression Tree is based on DynamicMethod but you can't optimize it manually.

The second rules

- Performance is represented by call mechanism and pure execution of method.
- call method using delegate means overhead
- inlining suppress call mechanism.
- DynamicMethod can only be inline in other DynamicMethod
- DynamicMethod and Expression Tree are most of time called using delegate.
- Delegate to instance method is faster than delegate to static method.

keep in mind :

- static method is often faster for methods with small body.
- DynamicMethod can be faster if call mechanism is not the pitfall.
- Expression Tree cannot be faster than DynamicMethod but can sometimes (rarely) be faster than static method depending on how you "express it".

conclusion :

performance depend on context.
keep using static method if it is possible.
Performance can change if optimizer change.